Conditional async ajax call in parallel
I have a similar question to Elegant solution to conditional AJAX call, where a parameter is loaded via an API call and cached before subsequent AJAX calls, with the additional requirement that this is run in parallel to another AJAX call.
Some pseudocode for this would be:
var myParameter;
function myUpdate() {
    $.when(
        // always make one AJAX call
        $.ajax(params1),
        (async () => {
            // retrieve the parameter if not already loaded
            if (myParameter == null) {
                let response = await fetch(someParams);
                myParameter = doStuff(response);  // some irrelevant magic here
            }
            // if the myParameter is 0, do nothing (return a fulfilled promise)
            // otherwise make an AJAX call with params2 + myParameter
            return myParameter == 0 ? $.when() : $.ajax(Object.assign(params2, {data: { value: myParameter }}));
        })()
    ).then(handleData);  // finally do some stuff with the responses in the handleData() function
}

The above doesn't seem to work as $.when() does weird things with different types of promises, which has resulted in this abomination:
var myParameter;
function myUpdate() {
    $.when(
        $.Deferred((dfrd) => {
            $.ajax(params1).then((response) => {dfrd.resolve(response)});
        }).promise(),
        $.Deferred((dfrd) => {
            if (myParameter == null) {
                fetch(someParams).then((response) => {
                    myParameter = doStuff(response);
                    if(myParameter != 0) {
                        $.ajax(Object.assign(params2, {data: { value = myParameter }})).then((response) => {dfrd.resolve(response)});
                    } else {
                        dfrd.resolve();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                if(myParameter != 0) {
                    $.ajax(Object.assign(params2, {data: { value = myParameter }})).then((response) => {dfrd.resolve(response)});
                } else {
                    dfrd.resolve();
                }
            }
        }).promise()
    ).then(handleData);
}

While it works, and I could tidy it up a bit using this answer to remove the redundancy, I'm not sure it's the right way to do this.

myParameter = doStuff(response): I doubt this is correct. To get the data from the response object you need to execute an asynchronous method, like response.json() or response.text(). So I don't see how you could get myParameter synchronously. Please clarify.

Stop using $.when(…).then(…) and $.Deferred when you have native promises and are using async/await! Also why mix fetch() with $.ajax()?

@Bergi I used fetch() since it was easier to await than $.ajax.
@trincot await resolves the promise so myParameter can be used synchronously. That bit was just there as a placeholder for other code which I have so it wouldn't be optimised out in the answers.

No, fetch() is not "easier to await" than $.ajax(). They both return promises and can directly be awaited. If anything, fetch() is more complicated because it needs something like a .then(res => res.ok ? res.json() : Promise.reject(res.status)) to function correctly.

Bad phasing. I mean it was easier to find examples of await using fetch. My knowledge of JavaScript coming into this was almost zero.

Use plain JS for all promise work, no need jQuery anymore, Promise.all to wait for several promises:
var myParameter;
function myUpdate() {
    return Promise.all([
        // always make one AJAX call
        $.ajax(params1),
        (async () => {
            if (myParameter == null) {
                let response = await fetch(someParams);
                myParameter = doStuff(response);  // some irrelevant magic here
            }
            if (myParameter) return $.ajax(Object.assign(params2, {data: { value: myParameter }}));
        })()
    ]).then(handleData);  // finally do some stuff with the responses in the handleData() function
}

